# Using jQuery.css to get value in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to set a variable to be the value of my `div` `border-color` property value

```
errorChartColorError = $('.col__item.error').css('border-color');
```

This works fine in Chrome but Internet Explorer 11 returns the variable as undefined

When I inspect the element in IE, I can see the border-color property and value

Do I need an IE hack?

Comment: I think you may have to specify a side, e.g. errorChartColorError = $('.col__item.error').css('border-top-color');

Comment: where did you apply `border` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border-color propriety can have up to four value; this mean you can set a different colour per each border (bottom, left, top, right).
Be more specific about which one you want to retrive, so:

```
$(".col__item.error").css("border-top-color");
```

or

```
$(".col__item.error").css("border-left-color");
```

an so on...

should do the trick